# How to annotate bean definitions with constructor-arg and references using @Bean in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring boot. I have a spring configuration xml file with bean definitions, please help me to convert the XML representation of the bean definitions as shown below to an annotated spring code representation using the @Configuration and @Bean decorators used in spring Boot.

[Spring-Config.XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggPXt.jpg)

Please help me in converting the above XML to something like below.

```
package com.bestbuy.integration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthProvider() {
        return new LdapAuthenticationProvider(bindAuthenticator());
    }

    @Bean
    public BindAuthenticator bindAuthenticator() {
        return new BindAuthenticator();
    }

}
```

Comment: You already converted it... What is wrong with this?

Comment: In order to configure the `authentication-manager` you have to extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and override the method `authenticationManagerBean()` with to create an authentication manager with your `ldapAuthProvider` bean. To create your dao bean is easy

Comment: The BindAuthenticator constructor takes in a constructor ref (context resource) and constructor arg (userDn pattern), i am not sure as how to write that.